# Spring MVC: Save form value to XML

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to save form in a xml format. There is no model class defined for this form. Form structure is something like this.

**- Section1**

- Field1
- Field2
- Field3

and I want to save it to

```
<section1>
 <Field1></Field1>
 <Field2></Field2>
 <Field3></Field3>
</section1>
```

How would I do that? 
To track which html field belongs to which section I can name them as name="section1.field2". It can help me to find out parent element of the field.

Comment: What about [JaXB](https://jaxb.java.net/)?

Comment: Right now I am trying to avoid any Marshalling/Unmarshalling for the performance reason. How would I get form values to controller at the first place?

Comment: Marshalling is the process of serializing your data to XML... Do you want to save to XML or not?! By the way I don't think JaXB should be a performance problem on modern system for small amount of data.

Comment: Yes. I do want to persist the XML into database as clob.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `XML` in `Javascript`  on `onSubmit` `Event` by traversing the `input` elements of the `form` using any framework like `jQuery`.

And creating the `XML` in your desired format is very easy if you follow [this](http://flesler.blogspot.in/2008/03/xmlwriter-for-javascript.html).

Use `flush()` to write it to any hidden variable, thereupon you can `submit` the form or you can post it using `ajax` as per your requirement.